# How to form the plural of "noun plus noun in possessive case"?

Tags: classical-latin, grammar-choice, genitive, noun

I would like to know what are the rules to form the plural of a noun plus a noun in possessive case. I am not sure if this is a correct description of what I am interested in let me give an example.

Say, I have the head of a horse, that is "caput equi." What would the plural be?  Is it "capita equorum" [both in plural] or "capita equi" [only the nominative in plural] (or still something else)?

I chose the example as it is relatively clear that the idea is one head goes to one horse and there is no head with multiple horses attached or a horse with multiple heads.

I do not care for the particular words, but I wonder if it might depend on whether it is an ad hoc combination or a common combination (like, for example, curriculum vitae)?

Indeed, the motivation for this question derives from a side-discussion on a question related to curriculum vitae on another site, but I would like this question to be focused on the general rules.

Comment: I'm no expert, so not offering this as an answer, but think they would have to agree in number. Eg,  *servi dominorum* would mean more than one master and more than one slave, whilst *servi domini* would be the slave's of one master. Conversely, *servus dominorum* would mean many masters owned one slave.  But I'm quite prepared to be proved wrong!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you mention "curriculum vitae", I assume you're focusing on metaphorical rather than physical uses, and on a name for something (rather than using it in a sentence)?

When talking about ideas rather than physical objects, it's not uncommon to put the possession in the singular and the possessor in the plural.

Consider:

- Suetonius' *De Vitā Caesārum* "on the Life (sg) of the Caesars (pl)"
- Lucretius' *De Rērum Naturā* "on the Nature (sg) of Things (pl)"
- Flaccus' *De Verbōrum Significātū* "on the Meaning (sg) of Words (pl)"

For actual physical objects, it's more like in English: use the actual number of possessions, and the actual number of possessors.

- *filius senatoris* is "the senator's son", one son, one senator
- *filii senatoris* is "the senator's sons", multiple sons, one senator
- *#filius senatorum* is "#the senators' son", one son, multiple senators (somehow)
- *filii senatorum* is "the senators' sons", multiple sons, multiple senators

Comment: How do you think this applies to physical objects, like *caput equi*? I'm inclined to say *capita equorum*, and I'm pretty sure *caput equorum* would sound strange to a Latin speaker, so perhaps you could incorporate that into your answer.

Comment: @brianpck Actually, it's an unusual feature of Latin idiom that singular for plural isn't unheard of. Gildersleeve notes it in 204 n. 8, but I seem to recall things like "the soldiers lost their life." I encountered it not infrequently in the *Aeneid*, and I believe in Caesar as well, whereupon it stopped standing out.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I upvoted it right away, but did not notice until now the latter addition.