# Latin plural of Curriculum Vitae?

Tags: grammar-choice, example-request, case

[**Curriculum vitae**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curriculum_vitae) (often abbreviated CV) is a common Latin locution present in a high number of languages, including English.

In English, as in other languages, how to pluralize these foreign locutions is a common problem. In some cases, the *naturalized* (i.e. English) plural is Ok, in others it is not. But most of the time, following the plural in the original language is a good alternative.

A google search for the [plural of CV](https://www.google.com/search?q=plural%20of%20curriculum%20vitae&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) seems to suggest there are two alternatives (*curricula vitae* and *curricula vitarum*), although [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curriculum_vitae#Etymology.2C_spellings_and_pronunciation) says there is debate on which of them is more correct than the other.

So the question is: **What is the plural in Latin for *Curriculum Vitae***?

Comment: Related: https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/267/near-duplicate-worth-making-separate-question?cb=1. Also related: http://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/1570/how-to-form-the-plural-of-noun-plus-noun-in-possessive-case

Comment: Are we looking for a Latin or an English plural? *Curriculums* is certainly not a Latin plural, but is arguably a valid English one.

Comment: @brianpck The Latin one, certainly

Comment: One might argue that there are several kinds of plurals in Latin. If several people each have their own CV, I agree with cmw's answer below that they together have *curricula vitae*. But if the merits of several people are combined into a single document, I would say that there is a single *curriculum vitarum*.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta That's true, but whoever heard of such a thing?

Comment: @cmw In joint grant applications one has to prove that all the principal investigators are sufficiently qualified. If those qualifications and personal histories are presented in a single document, it would be exactly that kind of thing. But I agree, it's rare. Usually separate CVs would be used.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta On second thought, I wonder if that's true. I think it would be more accurate to say "packet of CVs" or some other synonym of "packet" to make it clear it's not a singular document, but a collection of them.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's the former, *curricula vitae*. As the article linked in Wikipedia points out, *vitarum* would indicate that there are multiple lives mentioned per each *curriculum*. However, *vitae* as a genitive is describing the type of *curriculum*, and *curriculum* itself is the object that needs to be singular or plural.

This isn't so confusing if you plug it back into English:

Racetrack of life.
Racetracks of life.

Life is singular!

Latin tends to go even further, though, in making singular where even English would have a plural. So when the Gallic tribes were entreating the help of Caesar, the Sequani instead had "their head lowered" -- multiple people, one head.

> Animadvertit Caesar unos ex omnibus Sequanos nihil earum rerum facere quas ceteri facerent sed **tristes capite demisso** terram intueri. (BG 1.32)

Answer (score 10):

I agree with C. M. Weimer's response and have found three authors who use *curricula vitae* in their writings.

1. Cicero

   > ante Socratem Democritum Anaxagoram Empedoclem omnes paene veteres, qui nihil cognosci nihil percipi nihil sciri posse dixerunt, angustos sensus imbecillos animos brevia **curricula vitae** et ut Democritus in profundo veritatem esse demersam.... (Cicero *Academica* 44.5-10)
   >
   > <sup>Before Socrates, Democritus, Anaxagoras, and Empedocles almost all the old [philosophers] said that nothing could be understood, perceived, or known, that senses are narrow, souls are feeble, and **life's courses** are short, and  that, as Democritus said, the truth is deeply submerged.</sup>
2. Marcus Cornelius Fronto (2nd c. AD)

   > adulescentiae iuventuti prolixa **vitae curricula** data sunt. (Fronto, *Ad Amicos Epistulae* 2.7.19.14)
   >
   > <sup>Long **stretches of life** are given to young adulthood and youth.</sup>
3. Zeno of Verona (4th c. AD)

   > in ultimis **uitae curriculis** Sarrae uterum filius aperuit (Zeno of Verona, *Tractatus* 1.59.1.9)
   >
   > <sup>In the **last stages of life** a son opened the womb of Sarah.</sup>

Note that examples (2) and (3) are not especially cogent because they are referring to one life. In this case, a *curriculum* is not a "full course" of a life, but a particular "stretch" of that course. (Remember, the analogy is to a racetrack.)

Cicero's example, though, clearly refers to multiple "life courses," and should be taken as the model. I found no examples of plural *curricula* paired with plural *vitarum.*

(For reference, [here is a link to the corpus search](http://latin.packhum.org/search?q=%23curricul+~+%23vit&first=11) that I used.)

Comment: +1 Good thinking! It didn't even occur to me to list the ancient precedents.